# CSS style errors in Visual Studio while compiling

Tags: visual-studio-2010, css

Whenever I use CSS3 style commands (like Box-shadow, Box-Sizing, background gradient,etc ) in my Visual Studio 2010 projects and compiles it, VS shows one or more errors regarding CSS3 styles. How can I overcome this behavior of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can turn off CSS validation errors in Visual Studio from Tools menu. Select Tools > Options and perform the action shown in the following image.

[image]

Comment: this is great, what if you really have an error? (misspelled something?

Comment: As @MrBoJangles suggests in his later answer below, check "as warnings" instead of unchecking "detect errors"

Answer (score 3):

Up the top there is drop down text box (next to comments in toolbar). Open that and see if you have HTML5/CSS3 in there. If not, you have to download it from MSDN.

Comment: The download from MSDN for the CSS3 schema is available here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210

Answer (score 3):

I have a better answer for you than the currently accepted answer. It's actually just a small change to said answer and here it is. Just check the "as warnings" box. So it doesn't show up as an error (which is good because it ain't one), but it does show up in your pleasantly-ignorable warnings list still.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but first and most valid I found.

[image: expected identifier x found y]

**The main issue** was that our project had BundlerMinifier installed and configured
to run before build,

- It looks like that the errors are actually from that extension and
  not caused by msbuild itself. But I havent invested more time looking in to it.
- and the error was presented **when I started using "new" CSS feature ':has()'**
- https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/598

(https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier)

- **Also** worth mentioning;  I couldnt see where the actual build stuff causing the errors and creating the bundle.css happened before I turned on more "verbose" build output, VS >
  options > Projects and Solutions > Build And Run > MSBuild project
  output verbosity: to "normal" instead of default Minimal.

**However** we use webpack for all the bundling etc.
Ad the BundlerMinifier was only doing a copy from app.css renaming it to bundle.css 
So **my solution** was to remove the BundlerMinifier

Visual studio 2022, webpack,
searchwords:
"visual studio build how to ignore css errors",
"expected identifier , found .",
"expected comma or open brace, found )",
"visual studio set css version for build tools",
"visual studio build error for css file Expected identifier, found '.'"
"css3, :has()"