# Validation(CSS 3.0): "var (--my-border-top)" is not valid value for the "border-top" property

Tags: html, css

I am using custom properties in css ,

it is showing the following error

Validation(CSS 3.0): "var (--my-border-top)" is not valid value for the "border-top" property

my css is

```
<style>
    .samara {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid black;
       border-top: var(--my-border-top);
    }
</style>
```

and

```
<html>
<div class="samara" style="--my-border-top: 7px solid green;"></div>
</html>
```

it is working fine in jsfiddle, but in my project it is showing that error...how can i rectify it.. please help me

Comment: "it is showing that error" — What is "it"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're using the CSS validator that ships with Visual Studio (no other validator calls it "CSS 3.0").

That validator doesn't support custom properties or `var()`. Don't worry about it. In fact, I recommend [disabling CSS validation in Visual Studio altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933522/css-style-errors-in-visual-studio-while-compiling/7933567#7933567).

Comment: thanQ very much BoltClock